# Disable buttons while a function is executing in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

How can I disable some buttons while a function invoked by clicking some other button is still running in react framework?

I have two buttons and each one of them is supposed to invoke some particular function.

And to do that I am handling button clicks with a custom function handleClick(buttonId), and in the function body

```
handleclick(buttonId) {
    if(buttonId === 1) {
        this.calling_dummy_function();
     }
     else if(buttonId === 2) {
         this.calling_second_dummy_function();
     } 
  }
```

And when calling_dummy_function() is running, i want all other buttons disabled so that someone does not accidently invokes calling_second_dummy_function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new state that tracks processing state of a function, and pass it to `disabled` props of the `button` element.

## Working Code

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {processing 
          ? "Processing..."
          : "Click the button below to do some work" 
        }
      </p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setProcessing(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setProcessing(false);
          }, 2000);
        }}
        disabled={processing}
      >
        Do some work
      </button>
      <button disabled={processing}>
        Some other button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <App/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```